# Why 3sum solution using abstract list is faster?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was solving 3sum on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum but there is an solution with abstractList that seems to outperform all other solution

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
class Solution {
    private List<List<Integer>> res;
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        int target = 0;
        return new AbstractList<List<Integer>>() {
            public List<Integer> get(int index) {
                init();
                return res.get(index);
            }
            public int size() {
                init();
                return res.size();
            }
            private void init() {
                if (res != null) return;
                Arrays.sort(nums);
                int l, r;
                int sum;
                Set<List<Integer>> tempRes = new HashSet<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; ++i) {
                    l = i + 1;
                    r = nums.length - 1;
                    while (l < r) {
                        sum = nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r];
                        if (sum == target) {
                            List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
                            t.add(nums[i]);
                            t.add(nums[l]);
                            t.add(nums[r]);
                            tempRes.add(t);
                        }
                        if (sum < target) ++l;
                        else --r;
                    }
                }
                res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(tempRes);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

but when i code it like this it takes ~300ms.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
class Solution {
    private List<List<Integer>> res;
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        int target = 0;
        
                Arrays.sort(nums);
                int l, r;
                int sum;
                Set<List<Integer>> tempRes = new HashSet<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; ++i) {
                    l = i + 1;
                    r = nums.length - 1;
                    while (l < r) {
                        sum = nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r];
                        if (sum == target) {
                            List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
                            t.add(nums[i]);
                            t.add(nums[l]);
                            t.add(nums[r]);
                            tempRes.add(t);
                        }
                        if (sum < target) ++l;
                        else --r;
                    }
                }
                return new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(tempRes);
            
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how this is happening? I could not find any details on description and don't know why using AbstractList makes it faster than any code? Is it getting evaluated when code evaluater is reading from list?this only makes sense.

Comment: How are they invoked? The first form looks like it's evaluated lazily; so perhaps you never invoke `get` or `size` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation with `AbstractList` is cheating.

The online judge measures the time it takes for the solution to return a list.  This is extremely fast, since `init` is NOT called during construction.

Then the judge will check the contents of the list to see if they're correct.  This is when `init` is called to produce the *real* answer, but it is not included in the time that is measured.

Comment: I wonder if that should be brought to LeetCode's attention.  (Not a question for Stack Overflow, but) How might LeetCode defend against such cheating?

Comment: It would be easy enough to require an array of arrays instead of a list of lists.